how to use or condition in kql
Trying to write a KQL query where results should come when the table column Rawdata either contains any of the strings - job1 or job2 :-
 Tablename 
 | where RawData contains "JOB1" OR "JOB2"

The above gives me errror, what is the right way to do it

The right way to do it:
Tablename 
| where RawData contains "JOB1" or RawData contains "JOB2"

If "JOB1" and "JOB2" is a term then you can use the operator has_any
Tablename 
| where RawData has_any ("JOB1", "JOB2")

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators#what-is-a-term

You can also use in() if you want to search through rows.
table
| where <column_name> in ("<word1>","<word2>");

In this case, the entire row of the column must match the given word, then only it will give the required output.
Demo:

If you want to get the results by matching certain words in the row, then you can use regex.
table
| where <column_name> matches regex '+job[12]+';

Demo:

